# VB6 - CrystalReport .PrintOut() crashes the exe but works during code running debug

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

In a VB6 project in Japanese Win10 OS machine, this line is working fine during the code running and debug.

```
Private lReport As CRAXDRT.Report
...
...
...
Call lReport.PrintOut(False, 1)
```

But when I create the exe file and run it, this line runs correctly (creates the report) but exe crashes after this line immediately.

It is not consistent on all machines, on some English machines the exe working fine.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When it crashes, were there any error messasges?

Answer (score 2):

It is fixed by adding the exe file to windows DEP List.